# Error while implementing Junit 4 (Mockito)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

> here is my junit which i am trying to implement.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Power_Test {
    @InjectMocks
    ReportUtil w_res = new ReportUtil();

   CollectionUtil mock = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(CollectionUtil.class);

    @Test
    public void test_removeHashedSettings() throws Exception {

        HashMap<String, String> w_abc = new HashMap<String, String>();
        w_abc.put("abc", "89");

        when(mock.createHashMap("abc:89",":")).thenReturn(w_abc);
        Assert.assertEquals(ReportUtil.removeHashedSettings("1", "abc:89", ":"),"abc:89:",0);
    }
}
```

> I want to mock **createHashMap()** method which is static method.
>   Below is an error trace which i am getting while running the above junit.

```
 org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
  when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
  For example:
  when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
  Also, this error might show up because:
  1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
  Those methods cannot be stubbed/verified.
  Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
 2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

 at com.de.base.util.general.Power_Test.test_removeHashedSettings(Power_Test.java:34)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at Sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
     at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
     at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
     at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

> please help.
>
> here is createHashMap Api

```
public static HashMap<String, String> createHashMap(String a_NameValStr, String a_Delim)
 {
  HashMap<String, String> w_KeyVal = new HashMap<String, String>();
  if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) LOGGER.info("CollectionUtil:createHashMap:Hashing string: "+ a_NameValStr );

  if(a_NameValStr == null) return w_KeyVal;

   StringTokenizer w_StrTkn = new StringTokenizer(a_NameValStr, a_Delim);
   if( w_StrTkn.countTokens() == 0 || (w_StrTkn.countTokens()%2) != 0 )
   {
    LOGGER.warn("CollectionUtil:createHashMap:Invalid number of tokens to hash: "+ a_NameValStr+":"+w_StrTkn.countTokens() );
    return w_KeyVal;
   }

   while (w_StrTkn.hasMoreTokens()) w_KeyVal.put( w_StrTkn.nextToken(), w_StrTkn.nextToken());

  return w_KeyVal;
 }
```

Comment: *"I want to mock createHashMap() method which is static method."* what is the exact reason why you cannot change that to a non static method?

Comment: hi ,jobin I have Added createHashMap in the question.

Comment: You can't mock static methods with Mockito. Consider changing it to a non static method

Comment: so what is another option for mocking static methods?

Comment: this will help..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito

Comment: Thanks Jobin. I have tried writing junit using powermock . but getting some dependency  Error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45032761/dependencies-while-implementing-mocking-in-junit4-powermock   
can you please help me out in this?

Comment: Hi, Shraddha, I reviewed your create method and don't see any reason to mock it. It does not communicate with other system, does not require network connection. So, use it directly by passing needed input parameters.